# How to do anonymous phone call programmatically in iOS like Uber

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

I want to call programatically to someone in a way that receiver may not able to see caller's actual phone no. Instead he should see a dummy number like XXXXXX or something like that.

Comment: Guys please give a reason too for down vote so I may rephrase the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a service like Twilio
https://www.twilio.com/voice

This [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/ruby/rails) walks you through the setup of masking phone numbers to maintain privacy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by opening a link like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"tel:000000000"];
```

Comment: thanks for answer. But I think here we have to provide an actual phone number to make a call.

Comment: replace 000000000 with the phone number you want to call.

Comment: if you want something else then you have to use private api's